# grunt-closure-tools : ERROR - Parse error. identifier is a reserved word

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-plugins

I'm using "**grunt-closure-tools**".

When I try to minify simple JS file, everything works well.
But when I try to minify **AngularJS** library or **Bootstrap** library, I got next exception:

> Error: Command failed: build\lib\angular.js:9040 WARNING - Keywords
>   and reserved words are not allowed as unquoted property names in older
>   versions of JavaScript. If you are targeting newer versions of
>   JavaScript, set the appropriate language_in otion.
>
> build\lib\angular.js:256: ERROR - Parse error. identifier is a
>   reserved word 
>   */
>
> build\lib\angular.js:258: ERROR - Parse error. identifier is a
>   reserved word  if (isNaN(msie)) {
>
> ...................

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        closureCompiler:  {
            options: {
                compilerFile: 'lib/google-closure-tools/compiler.jar'
            },
            minify: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        src: ['build/**/*.js', '!build/**/*.min.js'],
                        ext: '.min.js'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-closure-tools');

    grunt.registerTask('closure', ['closureCompiler']);
};
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The error message seems very straightforward for me. Try to flag which version of JavaScript you are trying to minify.

Comment: Thanks. I've added next code and everything works: 
compilerOpts: {
        language_in: "ECMASCRIPT5"
}

Comment: Good to hear that :). Please post this solution as an answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is using ( language_in: "**ECMASCRIPT5**" ) during minification.

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg : grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        closureCompiler:  {
            options: {
                compilerFile: 'lib/google-closure-tools/compiler.jar',
                compilerOpts: {
                    language_in: "ECMASCRIPT5"
                }
            },
            minify: {
                files: [
                    {
                        expand: true,
                        src: ['build/**/*.js', '!build/**/*.min.js'],
                        ext: '.min.js'
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-closure-tools');

    grunt.registerTask('closure', ['closureCompiler']);
};
```